# Implement a feed stream in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I've a Django application that uses a `Product` model and a `Comment` model.

- A `User` can add a `Product` to its favorite products list.
- A `User` can leave a `Comment` to a `Product`.

I would implement a news feed in the home of my application, something like Facebook News feed.

Something like this:

- user_1 just comments product_3: "this is beautiful!"
- user_1 just added product_3 to its list
- user_4 just added product_2 to its list
- user_4 just added product_3 to its list
- user_2 just comments product_1: "recommended!"
- user_4 just added product_1
- etc.

So it's a feed with various type of sentences.

Have you ideas to implement something like that in a good way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Django ORM supports polymorphic associations. You can have a "base" entity like "Event" and concrete events like "UserEvent", "ProductEvent" and so forth. That's quite easy. Look here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/ search for "model inheritance"
2. Take a look at content types: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/
3. You can probably just save "rendered" text to the DB.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create a new model (let's say UserActions) in which you will trace all desired actions by adding an item on each of your others models "save" action. 
Then you can easily build a view for this model and generate a feed with all the actions in chronological order.